# No difference in result between async/await and synchronous way in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I wrote the following code:

```
import asyncio

async def write_after(pause,text):
  print('begin')
  await asyncio.sleep(pause)
  print(text)

async def main():
  await write_after(1,'Hello...')
  await write_after(2,'...world')

asyncio.run(main())
```

As result I got:

```
begin
Hello...
begin
...world
```

with pauses right after `begin`s. I was wondering why result isn't:

```
begin
begin
Hello...
...world
```

like executing program that uses tasks.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be possible to call multiple async functions in an ordered way, one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what's happening is you're waiting for the first result to finish, then starting the second function call and waiting for that result. I think what you're expecting is something like this:

```
import asyncio

async def write_after(pause,text):
  print('begin')
  await asyncio.sleep(pause)
  print(text)

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(
    write_after(1,'Hello...'),
    write_after(2,'...world')
  )

asyncio.run(main())
```

This will launch both coroutines concurrently and wait for the results of each. The result will be:

```
begin
begin
Hello...
...world
```

Answer (score 1):

@kingkupps analysis is correct. Unfortuantely, myy `asyncio` module has no `run` method (Python 3.7), so as an alternative:

```
import asyncio

async def write_after(pause,text):
  print('begin')
  await asyncio.sleep(pause)
  print(text)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(
            write_after(1, 'Hello'),
            write_after(2, '...world')
        )
    )

main()
```

Prints:

```
begin
begin
Hello
...world
```